# Proper syntax for lme() single random interaction term when 2 random effects are nested

Tags: r, interaction, mixed-models

This is a question about `lme()` syntax.  My response variable is 'response'.  My fixed variable is 'year'.  I have 2 random variables: 'student' which is nested within 'school'.

I want to include a `year*school` interaction, but I do NOT want to include a `year*student` one.

This is the syntax I have so far, but this seems to include 2 random interactions where I only want 1.

```
lme1 = lme(response ~ 1 + year, random = ~ year | school/student, 
            method = "REML", data = data)
```

Comment: I don't see how student is nested with school: could you please show what your data look like ?

Comment: just to be a little more precise, I would say you have two *grouping variables* (school and student [within school]), and either two random effects or three depending on how you set up the problem (intercept by school, year by school, intercept by student, where the first two could be combined into a vector-valued random effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much easier to do in `lmer` from the `lme4` package. Assuming each student has a unique identifier, it would look like this (untested).

```
lmer(response ~ year + (year | school) + (1 | student), data = data)
```